# Pagination change color on scrolling FullPage.js

Tags: jquery, pagination, css-position, fullpage.js

I am working with FullPage.js and looking for a way pagination change color if section's background changes. I used afterLoad event, but it takes some time to change.

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
        var loadedSection = $(this);
        if(index == 1 || index == 3) {
            $('#fp-nav ul li a span').css("background-color", "antiquewhite");
        };
        if(index == 2 || index == 4) {
            $('#fp-nav ul li a span').css("background-color", "#002e34");
        }
    }
```

Are there any other opportunities to change pagination (it is on fixed position) color immediately? Here is my pen https://codepen.io/ni4yja/full/GOYBzm/

Comment: You got a response on [the project's Github Issues](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/3043)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "onLeave" instead "afterLoad", so the color will change before the destination loaded.

```html
            onLeave: function (origin, destination, direction) {
                if (destination.index == 1 || destination.index == 3) {
                    $('#fp-nav ul li a span').css("background-color", "antiquewhite");
                } else {
                    $('#fp-nav ul li a span').css("background-color", "#002e34");
                }
```